# How to use $filter for birthday filed in microsoft graph?

Tags: graph, microsoft-graph-api

I have tried like below

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/people?$select=displayName,birthday&$count=true&$top=100&$filter=birthday eq '2017-03-14'
```

But i am getting an error like below

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ErrorInvalidProperty",
    "message": "The property 'Birthday' does not support filtering.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "79316157-c634-4b61-82f9-f6920370538f",
      "date": "2017-06-23T08:46:32"
    }
  }
}
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't filter on the birthday field.

The documentation lists for each resource lists which properties support `$filter`. For `user` the list is at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/user#properties.

Comment: Is there any way to get upcoming birthdays and work anniversaries (based on hiredDate) from graph api ?

Comment: Since it can't be filtered, you would need to get the full list of users and store them locally. For keeping your local copy up to date, you can use [delta queries](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/delta_query_users)